# "I will do as you said." vs "I will do what you said."

Tags: grammar

I have searched the Internet, it seems both are correct. But, I'm not sure whether the first one is correct or not.

Could you tell me which one is correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. *Do as I say* means "obey my instructions". Sometimes this phrase is followed by "not as I do":

- My dad, a big smoker, always told me not to smoke. "Do as I say, not
  as I do," he used to say.

It means "take my advice, even though I am acting contrary to it."